# check invalid js syntax in a whole project for EC6

Tags: javascript

IN my gulp tasks, I ran into this exception

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: StringMap expected string key
```

And I found there is an syntax invalid problem in a script of my project

```
function(date, LoanRate=0, duration=undefined){
```

This syntax works on web browser, but failed in Gulp `gulp-ng-annotate` task.

However, there are hundreds of js files in my project.

Is there any tool or command can find the invalid syntax?

[image: inline]

Comment: That sounds like a runtime error, not a syntax error.

Comment: Sounds off-topic to me due to asking for recommended tools...I would look at jshint.com

Comment: you can use WebStorm for figuring out the syntax errors while writing your code btw yes that looks like a runtime and not a syntax error